# Alternatives of nwb in react components

Tags: reactjs, npm, hadoop-yarn, nwb

I have a react applications which is very old and configured manualy. I have used nwb packages for building and publishing the packages. nwb seems to produce lots of vulnerabilities and that's why I would like to remove and replace with some other suitable packages.I have searched and found CRA( create-react-app) but as my existing projects already becomes larger, installing the create-react-app and moving the components might not be a good idea. Does anybody have any recommendations or ideas how to replace nwb to existing react applications.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an "eject" feature like some other CRAs. So you are stuck with having to deal with the pain of having to wire up Webpack (or equivalent) manually to replace all the conveniences that `nwb` provides out of box.

Alternatively, you can always fork `nwb`, update the packages to the latest patched versions, publish your own package for own consumption and live with it until you find better solutions.